# Error while migrating a Django Model: "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, django-models

```
class Game(models.Model):
    ...
    official_website = models.URLField()
    ...

class ReleaseStage(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    ...
    def off_web(self):
         return self.game.official_website

    source = models.URLField(default=off_web)
    ...
```

I have the above code (the dots are just other fields or methods that are not relevant) and when trying to apply the migration and create the tables in the PostgreSQL database, I'm getting the following error:

```
 TypeError: off_web() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

What I would like to do is set the default for `source` to be the value of that game's `official_website` field.

It's something that I can easily remove or change, but I'm really curious as to why it's happening and how can I resolve it.

I'm assuming it has something to do with how I'm calling `off_web` or that there's no instance of `Game` (although that's what `game` is, no?), but no matter how I've shifted things around so far, haven't been able to solve it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use defaults like that. And even if you could, what would be the point? `self.game` can't possibly have a value when you're creating a new instance, which is the time that the default would be evaluated.

Comment: In addition to Daniel Roseman's comment: You should rather do this in the save method. Something like this: `self.source = self.game.official_website if self.source is None else self.source`

Comment: I guess I have some stuff to reconsider. Many thanks to both for the info, will go back to the django docs and the drawing board!